# Align different labels with dropdownbox in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a menubar that looks like this:
[image: menu bar]

What I want is that the dropdownbox aligns right of the label. The first one (#Writers) is correct, altough it should be aligned a little bit higher because now it isn't vertically centered but that's not the issue.

**The HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="horizontalNavigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="issue.html"><span>Issue</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="series.html"><span>Series</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="writer.html"><span>Writer</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="editor.html"><span>Editor</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="letterer.html"><span>Letterer</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="colourist.html"><span>Colourist</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="coverArtist.html"><span>Cover Artist</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="inker.html"><span>Inker</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="penciler.html"><span>Penciler</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="tpb.html"><span>Trade Paper Back</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="publisher.html"><span>Publisher</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="creditsbar">
            <div class="creditsbarfields">
                <form action="getInfo.php" method="get">
                    <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="writerName">
                        <span>#Writers:</span>
                        <form action="">
                            <select name="writer">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </label>
                    <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="editorName">
                        <span>#Editors:</span>
                        <form action="">
                            <select name="editor">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </label>
                    <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="lettererName">
                        <span>#Letterer:</span>
                        <form action="">
                            <select name="letterer">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </label>
                    <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="colouristName">
                        <span>#Colourist:</span>
                        <form action="">
                            <select name="colourist">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </label>
                    <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="coverArtistName">
                        <span>#Cover Artist:</span>
                        <form action="">
                            <select name="coverArtist">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </label>
                    <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="inkerName">
                        <span>#Inker:</span>
                        <form action="">
                            <select name="inker">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </label>
                    <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="pencilerName">
                        <span>#Penciler:</span>
                        <form action="">
                            <select name="penciler">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </label>
                    <form>
                        <input type="submit" value="Next">
                    </form>
                </form>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="issueInformationLayout">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.creditsbar {
  border: 5px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 5%;
  margin: 1% 0% 0% 20%;
  background-color: feedb4;
}

.creditsbarfields {
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 2%;
  width: 300%;
}

.creditsbardropdown {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.horizontalNavigation {
  background: url(../images/navigation.png) top left repeat-x;
  border-radius: 75px;
  height: 6%;
}

.horizontalNavigation * {
  float: left;
}

.horizontalNavigation ul a {
  margin: 5px 40px 0px 23px;
  color: #578ba0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.issueInformationLayout {
  border: 5px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-color: #573700;
  width: 50%;
  height: 66%;
  margin: 1% 0% 0% 25%;
  background-color: feedb4;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full HTML code ? Alternatively, create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net .. That would be better to help us solve your issue.

Comment: I have added the entire HTML

Comment: @TimothyPersoon this is the code you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/y2m56/ so it seems like there is some css missing

Comment: Yeah, the images are missing. They are located in a folder in my /var/www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `display:inline;` for the dropdown lists:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="creditsbar">
<div class="creditsbarfields">
    <form action="getInfo.php" method="get">
        <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="writerName"> <span>#Writers:</span>

            <form class="dropdownform" action="">
                <select name="writer">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </label>
        <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="editorName"> <span>#Editors:</span>

            <form class="dropdownform" action="">
                <select name="editor">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </label>
        <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="lettererName"> <span>#Letterer:</span>

            <form class="dropdownform" action="">
                <select name="letterer">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </label>
        <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="colouristName"> <span>#Colourist:</span>

            <form class="dropdownform" action="">
                <select name="colourist">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </label>
        <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="coverArtistName"> <span>#Cover Artist:</span>

            <form class="dropdownform" action="">
                <select name="coverArtist">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </label>
        <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="inkerName"> <span>#Inker:</span>

            <form class="dropdownform" action="">
                <select name="inker">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </label>
        <label class="creditsbardropdown" for="pencilerName"> <span>#Penciler:</span>

            <form class="dropdownform" action="">
                <select name="penciler">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </label>
        <form>
            <input type="submit" value="Next" />
        </form>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.creditsbar {
    border: 5px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height: 5%;
}
.creditsbarfields {
    margin: 0 0 0 2%;
    width: 100%;
}
.creditsbardropdown {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.dropdownform {
    display:inline;
}
```

Take a look at the output of the code above [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/KarimAG/yCUEY/4/show/)

And here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KarimAG/yCUEY/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could give each span that contains a title a class and then do something like this: [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdCxy)

```
.title, select {float: left;}
```

Note: I didn't use your css because it looked like you are missing some stuff that breaks it.